# CSS column on the right, same height as container

Tags: css, height

I have a container with 2 divs inside it. One takes the left side of the container and the second one (rightBarItems) should be positioned on the right side but I want its height to be the same as the Container's height. Basically, I am creating a column to the right.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="itemMain"><?php include("itemMain.php"); ?></div>
        <div class="rightBarItems"><?php include("rightBarItems.php"); ?></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    padding-right: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px #492409,  -4px 0 2px #492409;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 2px -6 #492409,  -1px 0 2px #492409;   
    box-shadow: 4px 0 2px  #492409,  -4px 0 2px #492409;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two drity solutions (both of them have their issues)

The first:

1) postion relative the container 
2) and float the left element.
3) position absolute the right element and set its top:0 and bottom:0, right and the width

The issue of course with this is that the left cotainers content should be larger than the right ones

The second (if you can add more elements to the html):
1) postion relative the container 
2) float the right and the left container
3) create a new div that is the "bg" for the right element
4) position absolute that the same way in the previous: right:0, top:0, bottom:0 and the width
5) tweak the z-index if necessary

:O

edit:

quick sample of the latter solution: http://jsbin.com/ecaced/1

Comment: I know I didn't ask the question, but I wanted you to know that it worked beautifully and solved a HUGE problem I was having - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`height: auto;` or `height: 100%;` should work.

Comment: can not work, as long as the container has no specific height.